# Is it posible to assign variables for selective plays in a role?

Tags: variable, ansible

I have a role structure which involves various playbooks and I need to assign common variables to a few of these to avoid rewriting the code for every task in the playbook. Is this possible?

I understand that we can assign the variables when calling the role, however in this case I need it to be applicable to a few playbooks in the role.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. it's possible. Use [ansible_play_name](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) to select the variables. For example, create default variables of the role

```
shell> cat roles/test1/defaults/main.yml
my_vars:
  pb1: 'var1'
  pb2: 'var2'
  default: 'default'
```

Assign a variable selected by the name of the play

```
shell> cat roles/test1/tasks/main.yml
- set_fact:
    myvar: "{{ my_vars[ansible_play_name]|default(my_vars.default) }}"
- debug:
    var: myvar
```

The playbook

```
- name: pb1
  hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - test1

- name: pb2
  hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - test1

- name: pb9
  hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - test1
```

give

```
PLAY [pb1] **************************************************************************************

TASK [test1 : set_fact] *************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [test1 : debug] ****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "myvar": "var1"
}

PLAY [pb2] **************************************************************************************

TASK [test1 : set_fact] *************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [test1 : debug] ****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "myvar": "var2"
}

PLAY [pb9] **************************************************************************************

TASK [test1 : set_fact] *************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [test1 : debug] ****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "myvar": "default"
}
```